# when i am using this code for pop up creation it is giving sigabrt error after initializing UIPopoverController with a view controller

Tags: ios, tags, wiki, editing

when i am using this code for pop up creation it is giving sigabrt error after initializing
UIPopoverController with a view controller(Test2),

```
Test2 *pop=[[Test2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Test2" bundle:nil];
popUpnew=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pop];
popUpnew.delegate=self;
popUpnew.delegate=self;
popUpnew.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(150,75);
[popUpnew presentPopoverFromRect:mybutton.frame inView:self.view    permittedArrowDirections:
UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: will you implementing the delegate methods?

Comment: no Hchouhan i ahve give delegte self to controller only;

Comment: i think you give the delegate self to popovercontroller delegate. right?

Comment: ok so can you add UIPopoverControllerDelegate in .h file?

Comment: I have already did this in .h file

Comment: ok then can you write the actual error here which you face when you debugging?

Comment: when i run this code sigabrt error comes after this               popUpnew=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pop];

Comment: not this write the error which shows in the logs like this..

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:

Comment: if you are using xcode 4.0 or greater then press shift+command+y then you will see the debug area where the error is shown

Comment: Ok so Can you give the code for show a pop up window after touch inside a button

Answer (score 0):

What you have here looks fine.  Have you checked to see that mybutton.frame and self.view are valid?   Did you release it immediately after calling presentPopoverFromRect?

Have you tried testing by setting the delegate to nil?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Test2 *pop = [[Test2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test2" bundle:nil];
pop.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
pop.modalInPopover=YES;
pop.delegate=self;
pop.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(150,75);
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pop];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:mybutton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[pop release];
```